# Почему выбрасывается view.InflateException?

Tags: java, android

Использую в своем проекте вот такой вот PinLockView:
https://github.com/aritraroy/PinLockView

И все работает хорошо, но при инфлейте вьюшки из сервиса:

```
public void alertPin(String pkdName){
  view_pin = View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_lock_pin, null);
  pinLockView = (PinLockView) view_pin.findViewById(R.id.pin_lock_view_Pin);
  indicatorDots = (IndicatorDots) view_pin.findViewById(R.id.indicator_dots_Pin);
  pinLockView.attachIndicatorDots(indicatorDots);
  ...
  Handler h = new Handler(getMainLooper());
    h.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

            wm.addView(view_pin, params);
        }
    });
}
```

activity_lock_pin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.andrognito.pinlockview.IndicatorDots
    android:id="@+id/indicator_dots_Pin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:dotDiameter="10dp"
    app:dotSpacing="8dp"
    app:dotEmptyBackground="@drawable/sg_dot_empty"
    app:dotFilledBackground="@drawable/sg_dot_filled"
    android:layout_above="@+id/pin_lock_view_Pin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center" />

<com.andrognito.pinlockview.PinLockView
    android:id="@+id/pin_lock_view_Pin"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:keypadButtonSize="65dp"
    app:keypadTextSize="24dp"
    app:keypadShowDeleteButton="true"
    app:pinLength="4"
    app:keypadTextColor="@color/colorTextPrimary"
    app:keypadDeleteButtonDrawable="@drawable/ic_backspace_64dp"
    app:keypadDeleteButtonSize="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

layout_number_item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:clipChildren="false"
     android:clipToPadding="false"
     android:orientation="vertical"> 

      <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless/>
</LinearLayout>
```

layout_delete_item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buttonImage"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_delete_button_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/default_delete_button_size"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_backspace_64dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Вылазит следующее:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.widget.Button at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640) at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689) at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) at com.andrognito.pinlockview.PinLockAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(PinLockAdapter.java:41)
```

Ошибка возникает в адаптере PinLockAdapter.class

```
@Override public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) { 
  RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder; 
  if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_NUMBER) { 
    View view = View.inflate(parent.getContext(),R.layout.layout_number_item, null);
    viewHolder = new NumberViewHolder(view); 
  } else { 
    View view = View.inflate(parent.getContext(),R.layout.layout_delete_item, null);
    viewHolder = new DeleteViewHolder(view); 
  } 
  return viewHolder; 
}
```

Подскажите куда копать?

P.S. Хочу заметить, что ошибка появляется только при вызове из **Сервиса**

Comment: покажите вьюшку, как минимум.

Comment: нет, это не та вьюшка. Вокажите layout, на инфлейте которого падает

Comment: покажите layout_delete_item или layout_number_item, в зависимости от места падения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ошибка тут, так background задавать нельзя:
`android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`